# Javascript: document.removeElementById?

Tags: javascript, dom, document

Assuming I have an element called `menu` how would I remove this element from the page? Is there a `document.removeElementById` function? or something equivalent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No direct command but this will do what you need:

```
var element = document.getElementById("menu");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

You can wrap it nicely with function if you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work?

```
document.removeChild(menu);
```

Or

```
menu.parentNode.removeChild(menu);
```